# Why is my Dinosaurus class giving a <__main__.Dinosaurus object at 0x026B5210> error?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, representation

I wrote this class:

```
class Dinosaurus:

    def __init__(self, nimi, suurus, värv, toit):
        self.nimi = nimi
        self.suurus = suurus
        self.värv = värv
        self.toit = toit
```

But when I try to use it ...

```
Dinosaur = Dinosaurus ("Stegosaurus", "20", "sinine", "Liha")

print(Dinosaur)
```

I'm getting an error:

```
<__main__.Dinosaurus object at 0x026B5210>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That is not an error.

Comment: Check the possible duplicate link provided by @juanpa.arrivillaga. If you want a human readable string for print, you need to tell Python how to do so by implementing a `__str` method on your class.

Comment: That's not a duplicate. The linked question asks how to alter the representation of an object, whereas this one is based on the misapprehension that its representation is some kind of error.

Answer (score 4):

`<__main__.Dinosaurus object at 0x026B5210>` is not an error – it's the *representation* of your object.

A little experimentation shows that `Dinosaur` has all the attributes you assigned it:

```
>>> Dinosaur = Dinosaurus ("Stegosaurus", "20", "sinine", "Liha")
>>> Dinosaur
<__main__.Dinosaurus object at 0x7f893d9b5320>
>>> Dinosaur.nimi
'Stegosaurus'
>>> Dinosaur.suurus
'20'
>>> Dinosaur.värv
'sinine'
>>> Dinosaur.toit
'Liha'
```

If you want to change the representation that gets shown when you print instances of your class, you need to write a special [`__repr__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__) method to tell Python how they should be represented, for example:

```
class Dinosaurus:

    def __init__(self, nimi, suurus, värv, toit):
        self.nimi = nimi
        self.suurus = suurus
        self.värv = värv
        self.toit = toit

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Dinosaurus(%r, %r, %r, %r)' % (self.nimi, self.suurus, self.värv, self.toit)
```

```
>>> Dinosaur = Dinosaurus ("Stegosaurus", "20", "sinine", "Liha")
>>> print(Dinosaur)
Dinosaurus('Stegosaurus', '20', 'sinine', 'Liha')
```

There's also a [`__str__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__) method you can define, which Python will use in preference to `__repr__` when printing objects if both are defined. You should think of `__str__` as returning an informal, human-friendly representation of an object, and `__repr__` as the formal representation (which, if possible, should be a valid Python expression that could be used to make an exact copy of it, as in my example above).